# IE9 document.readyState not being set to "completed"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, domcontentloaded

I am trying to get some code to execute on DOM load complete using the code below which is placed in a script tag in the `<head>`

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        alert("Hello World");
    }, false);
```

The problem I am running into is that the DOMContentLoaded does not fire at all even after the whole body is loaded and also the `document.readyState` value is `interactive` even after everything is loaded.

Has anyone encountered an issue with IE9 not firing DOMContentLoaded and document.readyState getting stuck in `interactive` mode. I am using IE11 but emulating IE9 using the F12 Developer Tools.

[image]